# Dealing with <unresolved overloaded function type> when passing function pointer to function

Tags: c++, c++11

Let's consider:

```
void goo () {
    std::cout << "void goo ()\n";
}   

int goo (int) {
    std::cout << "int goo (int)\n";
    return 42;
}
```

And now I want to call one of those functions using some wrapper function defined like this:

```
template <typename F, typename... A>
void c (F&& f, A&&... a) {
    f (std::forward<A> (a)...);
}
```

With usage:

```
c (&goo, 10); // (X)
c (&goo);     // (Y)
```

Both cases fail (GCC 5.3.1) with appropriate errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘c(<unresolved overloaded function type>, int)’
error: no matching function for call to ‘c(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

As far as I am concerned the fail is because compiler could not choose appropriate overload when it has to initialize `f` object (too few information).

As a solution of course I can write usage calls like this:

```
c (static_cast<int (*) (int)> (&goo), 10);
c (static_cast<void (*) ()> (&goo));
```

To tell the compiler which pointer I really want to use.

Writing this `static_cast` for me makes code much more uglier, so I wrote a wrapper function for converting function pointer to appropriate one using template:

```
template <typename R, typename... Args>
using Funptr_t = R (*) (Args...);

template <typename R, typename... Args>
Funptr_t<R, Args...> funptr (Funptr_t<R, Args...> ptr) {
    return static_cast<Funptr_t<R, Args...>> (ptr);
}
```

and now usage looks much better:

```
c (funptr<int, int> (&goo), 10);
c (funptr<void> (&goo));
```

My question is: Do you have any better idea how to deal with that kind of situation? I am pretty sure this happen very often in generic code. So, please advice me something.

The ideal solution would be if I could use (X) and (Y) directly, so the magic trick with pointing appropriate overload would be done using `A...` and hidden to the caller.

Comment: I'd stick to casting. It may be ugly, but at least any C++ programmer can understand what is being done. Your way will require them to lookup `funptr`. And if you insist, at least make it so `funptr` work on a **function type** template parameter. I.e. `funptr<int(int)>`. That way the return type and parameters are much more clearly expressed.

Comment: `#define OVERLOAD_SET(f) [](auto&&... args) -> decltype(f(static_cast<decltype(args)>(args)...)) { return  f(static_cast<decltype(args)>(args)...);}` then `c(OVERLOAD_SET(goo), 10)`

Comment: Logically equivalent to the static cast approach, but I think this looks cleaner: `void (*goo_ptr)()=goo; c(goo_ptr);`

Comment: @cpplearner cool, it works, thanks for this answer. Still, I am not big fan of macros.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, sure, you are right, but you have to introduce variable anyway.

Comment: @StoryTeller Good point with function type.

Comment: I am extremely confident in modern compilers' ability to completely optimize away the extra variable.

Comment: Is C++14 an option?

Comment: @Barry, Sure, it is. I should also tag it as C++14. Go ahead.

Answer (score 4):

I mean, you can always specify the template parameter explicitly:

```
c<int(int)>(&goo, 10);
c<void()>(&goo);
```

AFAIK there is no way to do that in `c`, because `F` cannot be deduced (ambiguity between the overloads), and to make the compiler deduce the correct type, you need to change something on the caller side.

Answer (score 3):

If C++14 is available, then generic lambdas offer a solution to the "passing overload sets as function arguments" problem:

```
#define FWD(arg) static_cast<decltype(arg)&&>(arg)
auto goo_fn = [](auto&&... args) -> decltype(goo(FWD(args)...)) {
    return goo(FWD(args)...);
};

c(goo_fn, 10); // ok
c(goo_fn);     // ok
```

`goo_fn` is a lambda that transparently (as much as possible anyway) represents the overload set of `goo`. The trailing `decltype` is necessary for two reasons: (1) to ensure that the return type is a reference if that overload of `goo`'s is and (2) to ensure SFINAE-friendliness (which `decltype(auto)` would not.

Comment: This is a fairly verbose solution, and I'm working on a [pair](https://wg21.link/p0573) of [proposals](https://wg21.link/p0644) to reduce that to just `[](args...) => goo(>>args...)`. Guess we'll see.

Comment: epic. btw, FWD == std::forward<decltype(args)>(args)...

Comment: @JayYang The way I have it defined will compile faster, otherwise with the same behavior.