# SFINAE on invocable

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I am trying to make a template function that is will only get used for invocables that match a certain i pattern (in the example, accept `int` and return `int`). I tried this but it doesn't compile. Can anyone explain to me why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int foo(int) {return 0;}
int foo(char*) {return 0;}

template<class T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_r_v<int, T, int>>
add(T t) {}

int main()
{
    add(foo);
}
```

The error I get (VS2017):

```
main.cpp(13): error C2672: 'add': no matching overloaded function found
main.cpp(13): error C2783: 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type add(T)': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
        with
        [
            _Ty=void
        ]
main.cpp(9): note: see declaration of 'add'
```

Comment: Include the error messages that your compiler so helpfully provides. Also, your `int` functions don't return anything.

Comment: How can it possibly work? You have two versions of foo, how compiler would know which one to use? You can greatly simplify your example by removing all `enable_if` stuff and just try to pass this `foo` as an argument to template function.

Comment: @SergeyA That is the point of the SFINAE. If I replace the whole thing with `void add(int(*t)(int)) {}` it compiles. I am trying to achive the same via templates

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25871381/2069064) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46024823/2069064) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4159487/2069064) or ...

Comment: @baruch, no it is NOT point of sfinae. Point of sfinae is to select right overload based on a non-ambiguos name. In your case, `foo` is ambiguos name.